# Gluing cells along generators of $\pi_n(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given a representative $\alpha$ for $[\alpha] \in \pi_q(X)$ we may attach a cell along $\alpha$ to form a new space $C(\alpha)$ (This really is the mapping cone). One would hope that this has the effect of killing off $\alpha$, that is,
$$\pi_q(C(\alpha)) \cong \pi_q(X)/\langle \alpha \rangle.$$
In the case $q=1$ this follows quickly from the Seifert–van Kampen Theorem, since then one has
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(C(\alpha)) &\cong \pi_1(X) *_{\pi_1S^1} \pi_1(D^2)\\
&\cong \pi_1(X) *_{\pi_1S^1} *\\
&\cong \pi_1(X) / \langle \alpha \rangle,\\
\end{align*}
as the amalgamation relates $\alpha$ to the trivial map. One of the comments points out this is not true in general for $q \ge 2$.

What is the analogous result for $q \ge 2$ (with references please)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're claiming the cofibration assumption improves about the situation. Why is it easy to see the effect of squishing the image of $\alpha$ on the homotopy groups? In any case, your claim is not actually true. Your mapping cone kills the subgroup of $\pi_q$ generated by the orbit of $\alpha$ under the $\pi_1$-action.

Comment: I see what you mean about the the quotient not really giving you what you want. If you post your remark about the action of $\pi_q$ as an answer with a little more details and a reference, then I would consider this question answered.